# My Firewall script is blocking nginx Rtmp Client connection

Tags: networking, 20.04, iptables, firewall, nginx

My server is running Nginx Rtmp Server on Port 1935

I am running a firewall script to block bad clients who connect on my server over 30 times on any tcp Port
with the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

# The location of the iptables program
#
IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables

#Setting the EXTERNAL and INTERNAL interfaces and addresses for the network
EXTIF="ens3"
EXTIP1="92.186.5.80"
EXTIMESENTER=30

UNIVERSE="0.0.0.0/0"

#Clearing any previous configuration
#
echo "  Clearing any existing rules and setting default policies.."
$IPTABLES -P INPUT DROP
$IPTABLES -F INPUT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F OUTPUT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -F FORWARD
# Otherwise, I can not seem to delete it later on
$IPTABLES -F add-to-connlimit-list
# Delete user defined chains
$IPTABLES -X
# Reset all IPTABLES counters
$IPTABLES -Z

echo "...load xt_recent..."
modprobe -r xt_recent
modprobe xt_recent ip_list_tot=5000 ip_pkt_list_tot=128
echo "...load list limitation..."
#######################################################################
# USER DEFINED CHAIN SUBROUTINES:
# add-to-connlimit-list
# To many connections from an IP address has been detected.
$IPTABLES -N add-to-connlimit-list
$IPTABLES -A add-to-connlimit-list -m recent --set --name BADGUY_CONN
$IPTABLES -A add-to-connlimit-list -j DROP
echo "...Accept incomming traffic..."

# loopback interfaces are valid.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i lo -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j REJECT

# Just DROP invalid packets.
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP


# external interface, from any source, for any remaining ICMP traffic is valid
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p ICMP -s $UNIVERSE -j DROP

#allow TcpPorts
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 432000 --name BADGUY_CONN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above $EXTIMESENTER -j add-to-connlimit-list

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state NEW -p tcp -j ACCEPT

# Allow udp Packets

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state NEW -p udp -j ACCEPT


# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in. i moved it here to drop the attacker current connectivety as you told me
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# O.K. at this point, we will DROP the packet, however some will be dropped without logging just to make the log file
# less cluttered.
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p udp -m multiport --dport 33434:33448 -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp -m multiport --dport 23,2323 -j DROP

#this rule may not needed
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $UNIVERSE -d $UNIVERSE -j DROP
```

can i avoid blocking clients who are connected on my RTMP server?

Comment: Hmmm... that script looks familiar... I looked at your history, and I see I wrote the original, but for a different application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this rule:

```
# Allow any related traffic coming back to the server in. i moved it here to drop the attacker current connectivety as you told me
#
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

To way earlier, say after the ICMP stuff.

Add a new rule ACCEPTing your port 1935 stuff immediately after that. You didn't specify tcp or udp. I'll do tcp:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp --dport 1935 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

This will let anybody try to make a new connection to your 1935 port. If you want to prevent people on the bad guy list then put this new rule in between the bad guy check and the conn limit check, like so:

```
#allow TcpPorts
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -m recent --update --hitcount 1 --seconds 432000 --name BADGUY_CONN -j DROP
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp --dport 1935 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -d $EXTIP1 -p tcp -m connlimit --connlimit-above $EXTIMESENTER -j add-to-connlimit-list
```

Note 1: untested.

Comment: can i make an exception for those who connected on 1935 port?  like never add them to badguys list? so they can stay connected on my server not only on that port

Comment: as example protect all ports except this port 1935

Comment: If I understand correctly, then no, not the way I have done this script, which was for something completely different, originally. You might be able to jump to create a "good guy" list instead of just ACCEPT a NEW connection on port 1935. Then check it first.